# Getting no result when using cursor from django.db.connections

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I'm basically trying to run the following query. In a custom sql statement.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE input (
    id serial, certified boolean
);

INSERT INTO input (id, certified) VALUES (DEFAULT, True), (DEFAULT, False), (DEFAULT, True), (DEFAULT, False), (DEFAULT, True), (DEFAULT, False);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_record(_input input)
RETURNS input AS $$
    UPDATE "tests_person"
    SET certified=_input.certified
    WHERE certified=_input.certified
    RETURNING _input.id, _input.certified
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

WITH new_updated AS (
    SELECT upd.*
    FROM input, update_record(input) as upd
    WHERE upd.id is not NULL
),
except_updated AS (
    SELECT * FROM input
    EXCEPT ALL
    SELECT * FROM new_updated
)
SELECT id, certified FROM except_updated;
```

The code for that looks like the following.

```
from django.db import connections

sql = '''the above sql code'''

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

The sql throws no errors at all. But when trying to fetch a row I get no result at even though there should be results. I have the same sql in a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48a30/75 In the fiddle I get some results from the last select statement: `SELECT id, certified FROM except_updated;`

So not really sure why things get different when I try this out in django. For the record, I'm using postgres 9.6 and django 1.11.

Comment: Have you tried executing the update and select queries in separate `cursor.execute()` calls? See example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: I just tried to execute several statements (DDLs ending with a DML select) in a single `execute` cursor method and works fine. I used `from django.db import connection` instead `from django.db import connections`.

Comment: I tried to execute the new_updated and see what I got as results. That solved my issue in terms of why I didn't get any results. Perhaps I should delete this question? Not sure it'll be much useful for any other person.

Comment: @Jonathan, What is *new_updated* and also what was the issue?